# Qt Creator 4.0.3 reports, "Warning: Cannot find Visual Studio release redistributable files in C:\..." when redists are installed

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qt-creator, redistributable

After installing VS2015 and the redists, I installed Qt 5.6.2 and went to build some apps. Basic default-option console apps were compiling, so i thought all was well until I ran into this *warning* which is somehow blocking me.

[image]

> Warning: Cannot find Visual Studio release redistributable files in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist.

Which is weird, considering they *are* installed. And yes, I tried reboots:

[image]

Qt's help from Qt Creator helps not at all.

Any idea what files it's looking for, precisely? I don't mind copy-pasta patching this.

Here's the full contents of that folder when running `dir /s /b *.*` from that directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\arm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\dir.log
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\GraphicsDbgRedist
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.CRT
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.CXXAMP
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.OPENMP
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\concrt140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\msvcp140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\vccorlib140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\vcruntime140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.CXXAMP\vcamp140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.OPENMP\vcomp140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\arm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCXXAMP
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.DebugOPENMP
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\concrt140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\msvcp140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\vccorlib140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\vcruntime140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCXXAMP\vcamp140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.DebugOPENMP\vcomp140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCXXAMP
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugOpenMP
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\concrt140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\msvcp140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\vccorlib140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\vcruntime140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCXXAMP\vcamp140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugOpenMP\vcomp140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCXXAMP
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugOPENMP
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\concrt140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\msvcp140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\vccorlib140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\vcruntime140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCXXAMP\vcamp140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugOPENMP\vcomp140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\GraphicsDbgRedist\ARM
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\GraphicsDbgRedist\X64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\GraphicsDbgRedist\X86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\GraphicsDbgRedist\ARM\1033
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\GraphicsDbgRedist\ARM\VsGraphicsHelper.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\GraphicsDbgRedist\ARM\1033\VsGraphicsResources.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\GraphicsDbgRedist\X64\1033
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\GraphicsDbgRedist\X64\VsGraphicsHelper.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\GraphicsDbgRedist\X64\1033\VsGraphicsResources.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\GraphicsDbgRedist\X86\1033
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\GraphicsDbgRedist\X86\VsGraphicsHelper.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\GraphicsDbgRedist\X86\1033\VsGraphicsResources.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\arm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\arm\Microsoft.VC140.CRT
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\arm\Microsoft.VC140.OpenMP
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\arm\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\msvcp140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\arm\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\vccorlib140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\arm\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\vcruntime140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\arm\Microsoft.VC140.OpenMP\vcomp140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\arm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\x86
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.DebugOpenMP
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\msvcp140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\vccorlib140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\vcruntime140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\arm\Microsoft.VC140.DebugOpenMP\vcomp140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugOpenMP
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\msvcp140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\vccorlib140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\vcruntime140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.DebugOpenMP\vcomp140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugOPENMP
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\msvcp140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\vccorlib140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT\vcruntime140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugOPENMP\vcomp140d.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\x64\Microsoft.VC140.CRT
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\x64\Microsoft.VC140.OpenMP
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\x64\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\msvcp140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\x64\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\vccorlib140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\x64\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\vcruntime140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\x64\Microsoft.VC140.OpenMP\vcomp140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\x86\Microsoft.VC140.CRT
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\x86\Microsoft.VC140.OPENMP
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\x86\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\msvcp140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\x86\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\vccorlib140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\x86\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\vcruntime140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\onecore\x86\Microsoft.VC140.OPENMP\vcomp140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.CRT
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.CXXAMP
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.OpenMP
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\concrt140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\msvcp140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\vccorlib140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\vcruntime140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.CXXAMP\vcamp140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x64\Microsoft.VC140.OpenMP\vcomp140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.CRT
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.CXXAMP
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.OPENMP
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\concrt140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\msvcp140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\vccorlib140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.CRT\vcruntime140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.CXXAMP\vcamp140.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.OPENMP\vcomp140.dll
```

Comment: The same error occurs in `windeployqt`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to copy the *redist* fold in *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC* to *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0*.

Answer (score 0):

For Qt 6.6.0 + VS2022, you should set environment variable:
"VCINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC",
the last "" must NOT be omitted.

My deploy problem solved in this way.